# Safari inspector completely broken for my needs since OS update to Ventura 13.3.1

Tags: macos, safari

Since update to Ventura 13.3.1 Safari Version 16.4 (18615.1.26.11.23) inspector is now unusable for web development.

If I click inspect element:

- I can no longer turn off / on CSS properties.
- I can't add or delete CSS properties.
- All the line numbers for CSS are displaying as 1.

What can I do to get these functions working again?

Comment: Can you please do some additional analysis and edit the result into the question? If you create a new user account on your Mac and try it with Safari there, does the problem occur as well? Can you (in your main account) temporarily disable all Safari extensions and try again to see if it still happens? Can you try with different websites (including ones not developed by you) and see whether the problem occurs on all of them.

Comment: This may sound cumbersome, but right now there are just too many unknowns so we need you to help here with isolating the problem.

Comment: I've opened the site in a new tab and closed the old tab and now it is behaving normally. Other sites also seem ok. Hopefully it doesn't come back but I will do more checks if it does.

Comment: My answer isn't likely to be what you want, but without the data other people asked for to narrow this down, it's basically a fishing expedition in hopes someone else has done the troubleshooting and had this issue and can hazard a guess. I'll put up a "here's how to troubleshoot any issue you have after an update answer" that will either fix it or give us a foothold with some more data to narrow things down for you

Answer (score 0):

Since you've listed no troubleshooting, the first thing to do is make a new user account and log out of your current user and then log in to the new user.

Make notes as you test. Which web site did you open - which element did you try to modify. Are any or all of the items fixed? (screen shots / details here can be super relevant for others to attempt to reproduce or confirm your concerns)

Then restart your Mac and if you log in to the new account - do your test results from above repeat?

Next - make a backup of the Mac and consider filing a bug with Apple using the Feedback assistant so that they get the install logs and know specifically what went wrong in your case.

Then with your extra troubleshooting - it might be possible to start narrowing down if others are seeing this or it's just bad install / corruption / local issue to your old account or your install and you'll have to determine if your time / value of needing this makes it prudent to do an erase install to be 100% sure it's a true bug. (If it is - a second feedback after a clean install gets the best results IMO from Apple - they really dig into reproducable issues that we can reproduce and send them logs on a clean erase install - i.e. before you migrate any other data or apps or settings back or customize the Mac at all).

Best of luck - sorry there's no "do this" answer I can send from the details, but I know the value of troubleshooting things a bit to narrow down what actually is the cause of an oddity after updates and that playbook is well known and well tested.